# X axis relative to 1 not 0 in gap.barplot, how can I change this?

Tags: r, plot

I have altered the sample code that from the help file for gap.barplot.

```
twogrp<-c(0, 4, 5, 7, 2,3, 1, 7, 18, 22, 25, 26, 28)
gap.barplot(twogrp,gap=c(8,16),xlab="Index",ytics=c(3,6,17,20),
        ylab="Group values",main="Barplot with gap")
```

When I plot the above code, the resulting plot makes a 0 value appear to be a negative value, and a value of 1 look like zero.  Is there any way to change this so that if my vector contains a zero value, nothing is plotted, and if there is a value of one then I see a raised bar.  I have noticed that the sample files avoid ones and zeros, and that the plots resulting from the sample files have the x axis at y=1.

Comment: I don't know and I've been unable to find the cause in the code. Suggest you contact the `maintainer('plotrix')`

Answer (score 1):

There is clearly a typo in `gap.barplot` (plotrix version 3.5-5). Right now it is setting the bottom of the bars to the minimum `x` value rather than the minimum `y` value. Here's some code that will copy that function and change that line (if found)

```
gap.barplot2<-gap.barplot
if (deparse(body(gap.barplot2)[[c(20,4,4)]])==
    "botgap <- ifelse(gap[1] < 0, gap[1], xlim[1])") {
    body(gap.barplot2)[[c(20,4,4)]] <- 
        quote(botgap <- ifelse(gap[1] < 0, gap[1], ylim[1]))
} else  {
    stop("line not found")
}
```

Then you can run

```
gap.barplot2(twogrp,gap=c(8,16),xlab="Index",ytics=c(3,6,17,20),
    ylab="Group values",main="Barplot with gap")
```

to get

[image: gapped barplot from gap.barplot2]

There appears to be no easy way to set the `ylim[1]=0` without also setting `ylim[2]` (the max y-value). Lattice plotting functions would allow `ylim=c(0,NA)`. Which would be nice to force a zero line but let the rest of the function figure out what the default max should be.

So you can use this alternative for now. I would contact the package authors to let them know about this error. You can send them a link to this question if you like.